# setting JAVA_HOME in in OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: java, macos, maven

trying to set JAVA_HOME to execute maven but there is no way

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ export JAVA_HOME=/user/bin/
$ mvn
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /user/bin//bin/java

$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java
$ mvn
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/bin/java
```

Comment: You'd probably want to set it to where your Java actually is, e.g., on my Mac it's `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: great ! export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this - but substitute the java version with the one actually on your machine:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```